# How to automatically process data when a property is assigned?

Tags: c#, .net, properties

I have many times written a C# property that looks like this:

```
private string _Id;
public string Id
{
    get
    {
        return _Id;
    }
    set
    {
        _Id = value.Trim();
    }
}
```

The above snippet declares a string property called Id and makes it so that the `Trim` extension method is automatically called on the value passed in to the setter.  Without the `Trim` logic, I could have simply written:

```
public string Id {get; set;}
```

It seems like I've written a lot of code to accomplish something simple.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a better way?

Well you can make it *look* like less code (and clutter things up less when reading it):

```
private string _Id;
public string Id
{
    get { return _Id; }
    set { _Id = value.Trim(); }
}
```

Or even put the whole property itself on a single line:

```
private string _Id;
public string Id { get { return _Id; } set { _Id = value.Trim(); } }
```

But no, you can't make an automatically implemented property do anything more than trivial get/set to a private variable.

To be honest, it's really not that much *code* - it's a fair amount of *syntax* but you've just had to declare a variable and write two statements. I don't think that's really too much to ask.

Comment: did you intend to to not explicitly declare the backing field in your second code sample?

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon: I was only trying to show a difference in the syntax of the property part itself. Yes, you need the field. I'll edit to show the field as well.